# AppleScript: Set default colour for ColourPicker from variable

Tags: applescript, color-picker

I'm trying to call the ColourPicker from AppleScript using a variable as the default colours.
However I cannot get this to work.

To illustrate my issue I wrote a little code sample of what I tried, which does not work.

```
set defaultColour to do shell script "echo {65535, 0, 65535}"

set RGB to (choose color default color defaultColour)
##set RGB to (choose color default color {65535, 0, 65535})
```

I included the working, default code for reference.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: All the `echo` shell script does is return text, not a list of RGB values.  Your commented line is what works.

Comment: Thank you for commenting @red_menace. How would I proceed to turn the returned text into a valid list of RGB values?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for doing a shell script rather than just directly setting the variable to a list?

Comment: The reason I resorted to using a shell script @red_menace, is that I actually get those values from a curl command, rather than echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ***run script*** command you can always convert the "text-form integers list " directly to usual integers list. So, repeat loop no need at all:

```
set defaultColour to "{65535, 0, 65535}"

set RGB to choose color default color (run script defaultColour)
```

For none-secure text content from the internet I would use the ***text items delimiters*** method, like here:

```
set defaultColour to "{65535, 0, 65535}"

set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"{", ", ", "}"}
tell defaultColour to set defaultColour to {text item 2 as integer, text item 3 as integer, text item 4 as integer}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID

set RGB to choose color default color defaultColour
```

Comment: `run script` works, but it will try to execute anything - I wouldn’t be using it on unsanitized text from the internet.

Comment: @red_menace, you are right for none secure text from the internet. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned that the returned string is interpreted as text I started digging on how to turn the string into numbers. I came up with this:

```
set defaultColour to do shell script "echo {65535, 0, 65535}"

set currentColour to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of words in defaultColour
    set rgbValue to word i of defaultColour as number
    set the end of currentColour to rgbValue
end repeat

set RGB to (choose color default color currentColour)
```

*I got inspired by [@philastokes (via applehelpwriter.com)](https://applehelpwriter.com/2014/08/06/applescript-how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-string/).*